# Sum based on chart of Account Name

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm trying to create a Report Dimension (Income Statement Report) in my Cube and would like to perform calculation (Sum or Divide) based on Report Action attribute.  The Dimension table looks like below

[image: Report Dimension Table]

Could you kindly let me know if I could achieve this by MDX script?  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried few things and finally used Scope statement to achieve this.  I'm posting my solution here which works across all measures.  Please feel free to advise improving the current solution.

```
// Rporting Option  //

Scope ([Reports].[Report Item].Members);

//Total Sales//

IF [Reports].[Report Item].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Report Item].&[Total Sales] THEN 
    This = Sum({[Reports].[Sort Key].&[1]:[Reports].[Sort Key].&[2]})
END IF;

//Variable Contribution//

IF [Reports].[Report Item].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Report Item].&[Variable Contribution] THEN 
    This = Sum({[Reports].[Sort Key].&[1]:[Reports].[Sort Key].&[3]})
END IF;

//Variable Margin//

IF [Reports].[Report Item].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Report Item].&[Variable Margin] THEN 
    This = Divide(Sum({[Reports].[Sort Key].&[1]:[Reports].[Sort Key].&[3]}),Sum([Reports].[Sort Key].&[1]))
END IF;

//Gross Profit//

IF [Reports].[Report Item].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Report Item].&[Gross Profit] THEN 
    This = Sum({[Reports].[Sort Key].&[1]:[Reports].[Sort Key].&[4]})
END IF;

// and so on for more for other report totals

END Scope;
```